# Dependent Files with Less for Visual Studio

Tags: css, visual-studio-2013, less, web-essentials

I'm having a problem compiling Less files, and I think I am confused about the basic workflow.

Right now, I have one main.less file that contains all of my imports, and three dependent less files. If I import main.less into all three files, I get a lot of redundant CSS. What I think I want to do is tell the compiler that the three files depend on main.less without importing it.

Can someone please help me understand the Less workflow better?

Comment: It's all depends on what exactly those "dependencies" are. What stuff do these three files actually reuse from the main one? If it's variables and mixins (= *parametric* mixins, not plain CSS rulesets/classes) you'd better move those into separate "reusable" module and never mix "final" CSS entities (supposed to appear in final CSS) with shareable things meant to be resused (e.g. [#1399](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1399#issuecomment-33680478)). Otherwise it's just contradiction: it's simply impossible for the compiler to know what those depended items are if you don't import them.

Comment: Sometimes it's not always possible to have it strict, so there's [`(reference)`](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-reference) thing one can play with. It is supposed to perform exactly what you need, i.e. to suppress any CSS code generated by the imported file. But it's important to remember it's no more than a dirty kludge (e.g. [#2047](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2047#issuecomment-45207921)) to workaround flawed designs and/or keep a legacy stuff in until reworked. (In other words, `(reference)` always indicates something is wrong and should be redesigned if possible).

Comment: Besides it does not always work as expected since for complex depended chains it's not always possible to detect what is supposed to be suppressed and what is not (e.g. [#1968](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1968) etc.).

Comment: Aside of all above, it's a bit unclear if those three files are supposed to be used independently (but then how their CSS is redudant?) or they are meant to go to the same page(s) (then why don't you simply generate one CSS file instead of three?)

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate all your insights.